# Postgresql: Combine distinct/group by with ORDER BY RANDOM()

Tags: database, postgresql, random

I have a table as follows

```
id| page |   text
------------------------
1 | page1 | Hello World
2 | page1 | Foo Bar
3 | page2 | Baz Baz
3 | page2 | Some Text
4 | page3 | Some Other Text
```

I want to select 2 random entries - but each page is allowed to appear only once in the result.

I have

```
SELECT * FROM mydata ORDER BY RANDOM(); LIMIT 2
```

But can I combine this with `DISTINCT` or grouping?

Comment: You want 2 random pages from the base table (giving pages with many entries a better chance), or 2 random pages with the same chance for every page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007297/postgresql-select-with-unique-value/12012445](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007297/postgresql-select-with-unique-value/12012445)?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
select id, page, text
from (
  select id, page, text,
         row_number() over (partition by page order by random()) as rn
  from mydata
) 
where rn <= 2
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a *total* of two rows from the base table. Your query retrieves two random rows *per `page`*.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: that was my understanding (retrieving two rows per page)

Answer (score 1):

If you want:
... a total of two rows from the base table
... and give **every *page* an equal chance** to appear in the sample, regardless of how many entries it has in the table:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (page) *
    FROM   mydata
    ORDER  BY page, random() -- pick one random entry per page
    ) x
ORDER BY random() -- pick two random pages
LIMIT 2;
```

Or, with a window function:

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY page ORDER BY random()) AS rn
   FROM   mydata
   )
SELECT id, page, text
FROM   x
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER  BY random()
LIMIT  2;
```

You'll have to test which is faster.
If you are dealing with a big table and need fast performance, you can do better. [Here is one way how.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8675160/939860)

---

If, on the other hand, you want:
... a total of two rows from table `mydata`
... and give **every *entry* an (almost) equal chance** a to appear in the sample, effectively giving a better chance to pages with more entries in the table.
Chances are still not truly equal - your restriction increases the chances for entries of rare pages by definition.

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   mydata
   ORDER  BY random()
   LIMIT 1
   )
SELECT * FROM x
UNION ALL
(
SELECT m.*
FROM mydata m
   , x
WHERE m.page <> x.page -- assuming page IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 1
);
```

The parenthesis around the second `SELECT` of the `UNION` is required to allow for individual ordering.
Tested with PostgreSQL 9.1. Window functions require version 8.4 or later.

Answer (score 1):

Same as Erwin's answer, just a bit structured: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d3e83/6

```
with first_random as
(
  select * from tbl order by random() limit 1
)
, second_random as
(
  select * 
  from tbl 
  where page <> (select page from first_random)
  order by random() limit 1
)
select * from first_random
union
select * from second_random;
```

Same with a_horse_with_no_name's answer, except this is correct: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d3e83/12

```
select id, page, text, rn
from (
  select id, page, text,
         row_number() over (partition by page order by random()) as rn
  from tbl
) x
where rn = 1
order by random() 
limit 2;
```

Opt for the latter, it has simpler execution plan

Answer (score 0):

That may work:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM mydata GROUP BY page) t
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 2
```

Comment: No by this i will always get the text from the first occurrence of my main table.